# How do i display the Lengths of an object in 2.8

Tags: modeling, properties, panel

How do i show the lengths of objects in 2.8?. For example in 2.79 i could scale a wall or floor and it would display the length on the edges.

Answer (score 2):

In **Edit Mode**, press the little arrow at the top of the window to show the [**Viewport Overlays**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html?highlight=overlays).

[image]

Under [**Measurement**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html?highlight=overlays#measurement) in the menu that opens, enable "edge length.

[image]